# Callout from Lightning component client side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, callout

I need to call an Api from a Lightning Component and not from the apex controller because I want that the Ip that do the request will be the a local Ip and not one of the Saleforce Ips.

I found few ways to do that but  it is not clear if it is something supported by salesforce.

What is the best way to do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it's supported. Where are you stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: thanks, I didn't find any salesforce doc on it. I found serval ways to do that and I was wondering what salesforce recommend to use.
http://theapexhub.com/making-third-party-api-calls-from-lightning-component/
https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2018/04/Salesforce-lightning-fetch-data-from-external-api-using-ajax.html

Comment: You can use whichever manner you prefer.

Comment: If you are looking at a starting point, have a look at FETCH API. Please beware of CORS errors if you are going to make callouts to other domains from JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API